# Get Percentile on the Group by Result in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, percentile

I have a table which store friendship with tag like below

```
id | userid | friendid | tag
1    123       124         a
2    123       125         b
3    211       212         c
4    213       214         d
5    215       216         e
```

Now, i want to get the percentil of how frequent people set tag to their friends. Like for user 123, he set 2 tags to 2 users, for user 211/213/215 they only set tag once.

I tried query like

```
SELECT "userid", COUNT(*) as frequency
FROM "tag"
group by "tag"`
```

and i get result like

```
userid  | frequency
123        2
211        1
215        1
```

But how to get the percentil of the result?

I tried few queries but could not get to the result.

Comment: What do *you* call a percentile? Please show us the result that you expect.

Comment: Hi Mizhi, if I read your question correctly, the result you want for percentile is [1,75%] [2,100%], which mean there are 75% of users who tag 1 or less friends. there are 100% of users who tag 2 or less friends. Could you confirm my understanding here?

Comment: Do you want a percentil  value attached to each frequency or each user? If it is for each user, what do you want to show if there is a tide on frequency, such as 211 and 215 in your example?

Comment: If you provide the answers to the above required clarifications, we can possibly provide a solution to your post.

Comment: also, you tag mysql, which version of mysql you are using?

Comment: @Mizhi,  do you want the percentile from ascending or descending order? the answer below is percentitle from ascending order, but you want descending order, we can change the query to adjust that. By saying "from descending order", I mean "top 25% users tag 2 or more tags to their friends, top 100% users tag 1 or more tags to their friends."

Comment: I update the answer to calculating percentitle in descending order(a.k.a. "top 25% users tag 2 or more tags to their friends, top 100% users tag 1 or more tags to their friends.").  The current answer is most likely the format you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [MySQL 8.0+](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), which has added [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) support, you can use window function to get the result in a few steps.

Step 1. Group by userid and calculate frequency for each userid,

Step 2. Use window function to rank users by frequency, calculate how many users we have in each rank along the way.

Step 3. Use window function to calculate percentile value for each rank.

Step 4. Join user frequency with rank percentile value and sort them by rank_num to get the result you need.

Here is the query ([tested in MySQL 8.0](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o2rqWM9JnfvspEiozaqJ7W/0)):

```
with tag_with_rank AS(
select
    userid,
    count(1) as frequency,
    rank() over (order by count(1) desc) as rank_num,
    count(1) over (partition by count(1)) as rank_cnt
from
   tag
group by userid
),
rank_percitle AS (
SELECT
    rank_num,
    rank_cnt,
    (sum(rank_cnt) over(order by rank_num) / sum(rank_cnt) over()) as precentile
from 
    tag_with_rank
group by rank_num, rank_cnt
)
SELECT
    r.userid,
    r.frequency,
    p.precentile
FROM
    tag_with_rank r
JOIN
    rank_percitle p
on
    r.rank_num = p.rank_num
order by r.rank_num, r. userid
```

| userid | frequency | precentile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 | 0.2500 |
| 211 | 1 | 1.0000 |
| 213 | 1 | 1.0000 |
| 215 | 1 | 1.0000 |